# What does atof stand for?

Tags: c, atof

In C `atof`=`a`-`to`-`f`(loat) converts a string into a double precision float. I am wondering what the `a` part of `atof` stand for.

Comment: ASCII to floating point. From [Farlex](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/ATOF).

Comment: Unrelated: prefer `strtod()` rather than `atof()` if you care about validation and error checking and recovery.

Comment: @zmkm I am not sure but it seems a stands for alpha.

Comment: @WeatherVane I wonder why they chose such a name, because it is supposed to work with non-ascii encodings too. I guess just historical reasons.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow there *is* one alpha in `"1.23e4"` but mostly digits.

Comment: "In C `atof()` means I've chosen the wrong function for the job". Why? `atoX()` functions  have no error reporting and will silently fail returning `0` for something as wrong as `atof ("my cow");`. `strtof()` or `strtod()` provide full error reporting.

Answer (score 3):

atof is a function in the C programming language that converts a string into a floating point numerical representation. atof stands for ASCII to float. It is included in the C standard library header file stdlib.h. Its prototype is as follows

```
double atof (const char *str);
```

The str argument points to a string, represented by an array of characters, containing the character representation of a floating point value. If the string is not a valid textual representation of a double, atof will silently fail, returning zero (0.0) in that case. [1]

Note that while atoi and atol return variable types corresponding with their name ("atoi" returns an integer and "atol" returns a long integer), atof however, does not return a float, it returns a double.

A related function is sscanf. This function extracts values from strings and its return argument is the number of valid values it managed to extract (so, unlike atof, sscanf can be used to test if a string starts with a valid number).

Comment: `strtod` might be a better choice for validation then `sscanf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I'm not sure about the 'might' — something more definitive like 'is' or 'would' applies.  But I agree that `strtod()` is better for validation.

Comment: Agree with both, but at least `sscanf()` is one-step up from `atof()`. It at least provides a *succeed / fail* indication of whether the conversion took place (assuming you ***check the return...***)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Note that overflow with `sscanf()` is UB - although I have never seen such UB that was evil: at worse a nonsense value was saved.

Answer (score 2):

To best answer what the `a` stands for, go back to early 1970s when bytes cost approached dollars each.

Even if `a` originally stood for ASCII, `atof()` did not and still does not mean to convert ASCII into `double` as the implementation may have used an alternate character encoding.  With [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) or [PETSCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PETSCII), one could think of `a` as *alpha* and write code for `atof()` per that non-ASCII encoding.